# Angular Factory injection error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm learning Factory/Services. I coded this simple application to pass Fire Factory in Controller, but when I inject the Factory/Service in a controller it throws an error

home.html

```
<div class="home" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    Home <button ng-class="logut()">LogOut</button>
 {{test}}
</div>
```

app.js

```
cheers.factory('Fire',function($scope,$location,$firebaseObject){
  return  {name : 'Pawan Choudhary'};

});

cheers.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope','$location','Fire',function ($scope, $location,Fire) {    
    $scope.test = "working!";
}]);
```

It throws the following error:

[image]

Comment: you should define `var factory = {} ` then creating functions and variables in factory , then return factory

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi: Nope. That's not necessary.

Comment: @OP: I don't see how the code you have in your question could cause that issue.

Comment: @andrew I'm trying to do that only. :D

Comment: Use the un-minified version of Angular for better error messages

Comment: Ok! Thanks everyone I fixed the bug by removing $scope from the factory.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! Thanks everyone I fixed the bug by removing $scope from the factory.

Answer (score 0):

The header of your factory is not correct, if you wanted to add $scope, it must look like your controller header. try this :

```
cheers.factory('Fire',['$scope', '$location', '$firebaseObject', function($scope,$location,$firebaseObject){

         //your code

}]);
```